# Firefox overflow and sidebar in Google maps API infowindow

Tags: google-maps, firefox, overflow

i have done something small using Google Maps API and I'm really happy with using it. But one error occured; If i display a bit longer text in infoWindow, Firefox will always show me a sidebar with overflow. None of other browser is doing that.

Here is, what i have in infoWindow:

```
<h3>Whatever whatever</h3><span class="mark">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>
```

CSS:
    h3#title {

```
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    color: #000000;
    display: inline;
}

span.mark {
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: auto;
    text-align: right;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 0;    
    margin: 0 0 0 40px;
    color: #505050;
}
```

Anyone see any solution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

insert your content into a div.

click event will be:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
myDiv.innerHTML = '<h3>Whatever whatever</h3><span class="mark">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>'; 
infowindow.setContent(myDiv);
```

if it still doesn't help - try to add "white-space:nowrap" to your content style, such as:

```
infowindow.setContent('<div style="white-space:nowrap">....</div>');
```

or (even better) in a CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Micha's answer, explicit styling works well on Firefox and Chrome.

```
infowindow.setContent('<div style="overflow:hidden">' + var + '</div>');
```